# Bootstrap: Change background-color of panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

I found some previous posts about this, but the mistakes of the ones I saw were obvious to me, and unfortunately I couldn't find an answer to my problem yet.

I'm using a primary panel of bootstap:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">...</div>
```

I want to change the background-color of the heading, so I add this class to my CSS to change the background-color:

```
.panel-primary > .panel-heading {
    color: yellow !important;
    background-color: yellow !important;
    border-color: #F6E3CE !important;
}
```

The background-color of the heading, however, just keeps it's blue. What irritates me about this is that the color (font color) changes to yellow, which shows me that I'm editing the right CSS block.
And I can change the background-color of the panel-body just the same way which works fine also.

Any ideas about this?

Here's a screenshot to see that it's only the background-color that won't change:
[image: background-color won't change]

Comment: You can inspect you page source and see which bootstrap code is being used instead of your code. Like shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2vYH.png), you can see the source of the shown CSS code, so just look for the code from your bootstrap targeting that element. Once you determine what code is being used, make sure to use either the same or more dominant CSS selectors for the code you want to use to override that code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much! With your help I just found out that it's the following block:     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#2e6da4 0,#2e6da4 100%); In the chrome development tools I can see that it's in the file "gradients.less" - I was searching in "bootstrap.css". But anyhow, where can I find this "gradients.less" file, it's not included to my bootstrap folder. I can see that it has some effect when I change it in chrome, but I don't know where the file is to change it long term.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a bootstrap file. It sounds like a completely separate CSS file that is causing this problem. This file can technically be stored anywhere in your project, so the only thing I can suggest is searching your project files for the "gradients" file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `background-image` or `background` property to override the default background color.

like this

```
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,yellow 0, #dbff46 100%);
```

or

```
background:yellow;
```

Comment: Hi Wahdan, Thanks very much. Yes, that seems to be the right property indeed, it worked!

Comment: The only question that remains: When I look in chrome console, the initial colors for this aren't defined in "bootstrap.css" but in a file called "gradients.less". I can change them now in my own css-file but it only works, if I use the keyword !important. That means, it's predefined somewhere else. I think it's not the best way to use !important too much, so I'd like to know where I can change the styling long term. I can't find any .less files in my downloaded bootstrap folder.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be more specific with your code, you didnt mention how your elements are structured, the A > B selector means that it will match the element B that has an element A parent. To help  you more with your question maybe add some code snippet so you can get help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm very new to stackoverflow. It seems that I have to add a new comment to post another screenshot.

Now this is really strange, when I identify the source of the file "gradients.less" in chrome, I get this Screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3yks.png)

According to this picture, I have a directory ../bootstrap/css/less/mixins/gradients.less

But actually the directory that I have is: ../bootstrap/css and there are only files in this, like "bootstrap.css" - no subfolder "less" - no subfolders at all.